# How can you create a CPPN-NEAT in tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I want to create a CPPN-NEAT similar to that found in picbreeder or neurogram except mines is with soft robots similar to many that have been done before. I want to know how I could create this CPPN-NEAT in tensorflow.js and if it is even possible. The objectives of the CPPN-NEAT would be:

1. To be able to have different activation functions for each node(I don't know if possible with tensorflow.js)
2. For it to not be a network where every node in one layer connects to every node in the next
3. Layers can skip other layers like where the input skips the hidden layer and goes directly to the output
4. The network can add nodes and connections by itself(NEAT) basically altering its structure based on performance
5. The network can be recurrent and nodes can be the inputs of each other

I don't know if this can be done in tensorflow.js and if it can't, do you know anything else that I can use that is simple to use and javascript.

Thank you if you respond
(Also it would be helpful to include some code examples instead of just explaining the process because I have already looked at a lot of websites on CPPN's and NEAT's)